# Change title bar color in flutter windows desktop

Tags: windows, flutter, titlebar

I am developing a windows desktop application and would like to change the title bar color if possible. for example I would like to go from something like this: [image]

to something like this: [image]

Is it possible using flutter and how to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for this kind of customization, you will need to use the [bitsdojo_windows](https://github.com/bitsdojo/bitsdojo_window) community package, that allows you to customize the appearance of the window

Comment: That library is very buggy and crashy fyi.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party but you can use [window_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/window_manager) to achieve what you want.
In order to hide the title bar, you should use `setTitleBarStyle()` method before your `runApp` call, so the user will not see a lag or delay in UI.
Here's a minimal example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:window_manager/window_manager.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); //Must be called
  await windowManager.ensureInitialized(); //Must be called
  //waitUntilReadyToShow ==> Optional method to use, requires modification of native runner - Read docs of the package.
  await windowManager.waitUntilReadyToShow().then((_) async {
    await windowManager.setTitleBarStyle(TitleBarStyle.hidden); //Hiding the titlebar
    await windowManager.setTitle("I don't have a titlebar!"); //We don't have a titlebar, this title appears in Task Manager for example.
    await windowManager.show(); //Finally show app window.
  });
  runApp(const MyApp());
}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text('My Titlebar-less app!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: not working at alll

Comment: @NicholasJela Please let me know "how" it's not working. I will be happy to explain further and edit the answer if needed.

Comment: Title is not displaying due to color Issue